# How do I change a value from firestore database with onClick event on React?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I want to change my task status in firestore database but even I tried all the ways, it could not work. All I want is change the "status" field from my collection which is inside in the document with given id.

My directory like this: `mycollection -> id -> status:"waiting"`

Firstly, I imported these:

```
import { db } from "../../../firebase";
import { getDatabase, ref, set } from "firebase/database";
```

In best case, which is:

```
const writeUserData = (id, inFieldStatus) => {
    const db = getDatabase();
    set(ref(db, '/mycollection' + id), {
        status: inFieldStatus
    });
}
```

Ps: I can successfully get my database in 'db', there is no mistake for that. I have my database name/id correctly.

it gives me this error:
`@firebase/database: FIREBASE WARNING: Firebase error. Please ensure that you spelled the name of your Firebase correctly`

Also I call the function correctly and passed 2 of my variables like clicked item's id and wanted status as a string.

I pass it as:
`onClick={(e) => writeUserData(item.id,"approved")}`

Also, I do these in my firebase.js file:

```
const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig)
const db = getFirestore(app)
export {db}
```

Problem is solved by these line of function:

```
async function handleData (data,inFieldStatus) {
        const docData = {
            docData1: data.docData1,
            docData2: data.docData2,
            ...,
            status: inFieldStatus
        };
        await setDoc(doc(db, "mycollection", data.id), docData)
        }
```

Comment: You say that you want to modify Firebase and also tagged as such, but the only code that writes to a database (`set(ref(...))` actually does so to the Realtime Database.  While both databases are part of Firebase, they're completely separate, and the API for one doesn't work on the other.

Comment: I am using firestore database for sure as I mentioned but I tried every code in google to modify my data. @FrankvanPuffelen , I don't know what to do about that and which code is the firestore or realtime, it confuses me a bit.

Comment: Writing data to Firestore is covered here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data

Comment: Thank you @FrankvanPuffelen , solved it with "Data Types" part.